# Griddb Service Not Starting

Tags: ubuntu, griddb

I have installed GriddB on Ubuntu successfully but when I try to start the service on the terminal, that is to run Griddb, using this command

```
sudo systemctl start gridstore
```

it fails with an error shown below

```
Job for gridstore.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status gridstore.service" and "journalctl -xeu gridstore.service" for 
details.
```

I checked the details using suggested command,

```
journalctl -xeu gridstore.service
```

I get this console stackTrace

```
Sep 02 08:56:10 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40932]: Starting gridstore service:
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40945]: AD0103: Unable to start node.
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40945]: Confirm event logs (gridstore- 
YYYYMMDD-n.log, gsstartup.log).
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40932]: Stopping gridstore service:
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40947]: A00104: Failed to connect node. 
(node=127.0.0.1:10040)
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40947]: Confirm node is started.
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40947]: URLError <urlopen error [Errno 111] 
Connection refused>
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40932]: F01006: Leavecluster error
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40932]: Stopped.
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40932]: F01002: Startnode error
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar gridstore[40932]: [ FAILED ]
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Control process exited, 
code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
p 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Failed with result 
'exit-code'.
Sep 02 08:56:11 nebucodenezzar systemd[1]: Failed to start GridDB database server..
```

The command `systemctl status gridstore.service` gives some extra information:

```
× gridstore.service - GridDB database server.
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-09-02 08:56:11 EAT; 26min ago
Process: 40932 ExecStart=/usr/griddb/bin/gridstore start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    CPU: 370ms
```

I've tried to start the node manually using:

```
sudo /usr/bin/gs_startnode
```

I then fall into this error:

```
A00105: GS_HOME, GS_LOG environment variable not set.
```

Even after continuously setting the variables :

```
export GS_HOME=/usr/griddb-5.3.0
export GS_LOG=/usr/griddb-5.3.0/log
```

and restarting the terminal, the `variable not set` error and the Griddb service won't start

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error

```
A00105: GS_HOME, GS_LOG environment variable not set.
```

Run the following command in your gsadm account;

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

This will set up the environment variable