# Error updating .bash_profile when installing GridDB on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, griddb

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C16HA.png)

I am following the video (https://docs.griddb.net/latest/gettingstarted/using-apt/#install-with-apt-get) on installing GridDB with Ubuntu but am getting an error when trying to run `gs_stat -u admin/admin`

The video mentions that you must update your bash_profile but I am unable to do the required steps.Why is it saying for me that .bash_profile is permission denied?

Comment: I'm not sure what fixed the issue but I have since installed Java since that was in the error message. I also noticed I was in the wrong directory

Comment: After doing `sudo su gsadm` I also needed to do `cd`

Answer (score 2):

The issue with running `gs_stat -u admin/admin` and .bash_profile.yml is related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77034147/3410041

The most common error observed with running the command is the inability to resolve the Grid DB environment variables. Thus, all you need is to run `source ~/.bash_profile`. There is no need to edit the bash_profile file.